# Group data based on the mode in sql

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a large dataset in Microsoft Access with postcodes in one column and an unordered category in the next as follows:

```
Postcode     |     Class
--------------------------
1111AA       |       A
1111AA       |       B
1111AA       |       A
1111AB       |       C
1111AB       |       C
1111AB       |       A
```

I would like to group the data such that on the left-hand side I have one Postcode for the mode of the Class on the right. The classes are unordered (i.e: A is not better than B, nor C better than B). I have tried using queries but they only really work for numerical data and I can only seem to use these techniques for finding averages.

So in the end I want:

```
Postcode     |     Class
------------------------
1111AA       |       A
1111AB       |       C
```

Comment: Your description is quiet vague. Could you please edit your post with more clarity and also a mock **Expected output**. So we will see what you actually want.

Comment: Done the mock expected output. Obviously, with a large dataset it would be difficult to do this manually so if possible, is there some simulation function I could perhaps use?

Comment: Still unclear with the description bit. Why is 1111AA | B not in the result? Why is 1111AB | A not in the result too?

Comment: You mean "mode" as the value with maximal frequency? Probably you have to create two queries (select statements). In inner query you group by postcode and class and find row count; then from these results you group by postcode and find maximum count and corresponding class value. In MS-Access you best have to define inner query as separate one, because you need use it twice in outer query. (I know that my text is confusing - but in comments this is probably allowed :))

Comment: This is probably what you need: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/153747 (you want the top 1 per group, grouped by postcode)

Comment: I mean 'mode'as in the letter with the max frequency. So in my final table i only want each postcode to appear once on the left-hand side with the corresponding Class A,B or C which appeared the most for each Postcode.

Comment: sounds about right StevieG, i'll give it a go. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

via most frequency per postal code, you would need a pre-query first and then match that count... basically doing a triple-process against the table.

The third level in alias (QPerClass) gets on a per postal code, each class and their respective counts.  A max classification count of 3 in one postal code vs count 5 in another are two separate things, and you don't want the overall most popular 5 count if such other postal code only has 3, it would never find a corresponding match.

So, per your sample data, this would result in

```
PostCode    Class  Count
1111AA      A      2
1111AA      B      1

1111AB      C      2
1111AB      A      1
```

From that, we need each postal code's MAXIMUM COUNT, but you can't grab the class associated with it as which you can't say grab the class with the max count, and you cant do a limit 1 per postal code.. this would result in

```
1111AA      2
1111AB      2
```

Now that you have the count per postal code, join that to your original table and apply a group by AND a having so that the outer-level HAVING COUNT(*) matches the MAX() count as determined in the second step.

```
select
      pc.postCode,
      pc.class,
      MaxPostByCode.MaxCount
   from
      PostalCodes pc
         JOIN ( select QPerClass.postCode,
                       max( QPerClass.perClassCount ) MaxCount
                   from 
                      ( select pc2.postcode,
                              pc2.class,
                              count(*) perclassCount
                           from
                              postalcodes pc2
                           group by
                              pc2.postcode,
                              pc2.class ) QPerClass
                   group by
                      QPerClass.postCode ) MaxByPostCode
            on pc.postcode = MaxByPostCode.postCode
   group by
      pc.postCode,
      pc.class,
      MaxPostByCode.MaxCount
   having
      count(*) = MaxPostByCode.MaxCount
```

Now, if you have an instance where there are multiple entries that have the same MODE (max count per class), then you would have to wrap it up yet again to get the MIN( CLASS ) that qualified the HAVING clause grouped by postal code, such as

```
select
      m.postcode,
      min( m.class )
   from
      ( entire query above with the HAVING clause ) m
   group by
      m.postcode
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want...

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES PostCode, Class
FROM @Temp
GROUP BY PostCode, Class
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

Comment: I don't think MS Access supports the `WITH TIES` clause. And anyway, your query would only work, if the highest frequency were the same for all post codes (as is 2 in OP's example). I don't think we can take this for granted.

Answer (score 0):

Use a correlated subquery to get the most often occurring class for a postcode:

```
select postcode, class
from mytable as m
where class =
(
  select top 1 m2.class
  from mytable m2
  where m2.postcode = m.postcode
  group by m2.class
  order by count(*) desc
)
group by m.postcode, m.class;
```

In case of a tie, one class is picked arbitrarily.